# Redis in Python: difference of with and without multi() function

Tags: python, redis, transactions

The [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/docs/interact/transactions/) says:

> A Redis transaction is entered using the MULTI command.

Here's an example which uses the `Python` API to interact with a Redis server:

```
r = redis.Redis(...)
pipe = r.pipeline()
current_value = pipe.get('someKey')
#pipe.multi()
pipe.set('someKey', current_value + 1)
pipe.execute()
```

What difference does the `pipe.multi()` instruction make?

What's the right way to achieve *atomicity*?

Answer (score 3):

`Pipelining` is a mechanism that saves you the **(RTT)** Round Trip Time, when you actually want to batch the update/query of keys and you don't need the reply back for each key by itself.

`Multi` will actually make the transaction atomic; so a set of commands being combined into one command, an [example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/zVXsg0bjrbg) would be:

```
MULTI 
SADD foo a 
SADD foo b 
EXEC
```

If someone queries for the value of `foo` before OR during the transaction is happening they will get `NULL` while someone queries after the transaction is finished will get `a,b` , so there is no chance that you will be getting `a` by itself.

The Python/Redis API reference is setting it by default to `MULTI` and you can set it to false if you don't need it. From the [Reference](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis):

> MULTI/EXEC: These are implemented as part of the Pipeline class. The pipeline is wrapped with the MULTI and EXEC statements by default when it is executed, which can be disabled by specifying transaction=False.

Comment: So, `multi()` is a must for being atomic in `python` API.

Comment: The API reference is setting it by default and you can set it to false if you dont need it , `MULTI/EXEC: These are implemented as part of the Pipeline class. The pipeline is wrapped with the MULTI and EXEC statements by default when it is executed, which can be disabled by specifying transaction=False. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis