# How do watch() and multi() redis instructions really work?

Tags: python, redis, transactions, watch, redis-py

I'm trying to understand the correct use of commands `multi` and `watch` for the access to a database Redis.

#### The context

I'm using:

- the Python Client for Redis [redis-py version 3.5.3](https://pypi.org/project/redis/3.5.3/).
- the version of the Redis server is **Redis server v=5.0.5**.

#### Other links

I have made many researches on Internet and I have found some useful link about the main topic of my question:

- [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695837/redis-in-python-difference-of-with-and-without-multi-function) is useful but not exhaustive
- [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73428663/using-multi-with-multiple-redis-cli) explains well how works the `multi` command

#### Example code

I have written and executed the following code where is used the instruction `watch` associated to an example Redis key called `keyWatch`:

```py
r = redis.Redis()

def key_incr():
    print('keyWatch before incr = ' + r.get('keyWatch').decode("utf-8"))
    pipe = r.pipeline()
    pipe.watch('keyWatch')
    pipe.multi()
    pipe.incr('keyWatch')
    pipe.execute()
    print('keyWatch after incr = ' + r.get('keyWatch').decode("utf-8"))

key_incr()
```

Previous code can be correctly executed and if the initial value of `keyWatch` is `9`, the output of the execution is :

```
keyWatch before incr = 9
keyWatch after incr = 10
```

If I remove the instruction `multi()` from the code it becomes:

```py
r = redis.Redis()

def key_incr():
    print('keyWatch before incr = ' + r.get('keyWatch').decode("utf-8"))
    pipe = r.pipeline()
    pipe.watch('keyWatch')
    # NOTE: here the multi() instruction is commented
    #pipe.multi()
    pipe.incr('keyWatch')
    pipe.execute()
    print('keyWatch after incr = ' + r.get('keyWatch').decode("utf-8"))

key_incr()
```

Its execution raise the following exception:

```
raise WatchError("Watched variable changed.")
redis.exceptions.WatchError: Watched variable changed.
```

My need is to avoid that other clients modify the key `keyWatch` while are executed the instructions of the transaction, but why in my example code the `WatchError` exception is raised only if the `multi()` instruction is not present?

Thanks

---

#### Use of MONITOR

Here I edit my question and add what I have discovered by the use of the Redis command `monitor`.

By `redis-cli monitor` (MONITOR in the rest of the post) I can see the requests to the server during the execution of previous 2 snippets of code.

#### Monitor info with `multi` instruction

For the case where the `multi()` instruction is present requests are the following:

```
> redis-cli monitor
OK
1681733993.273545 [0 127.0.0.1:46342] "GET" "keyWatch"
1681733993.273790 [0 127.0.0.1:46342] "WATCH" "keyWatch"
1681733993.273934 [0 127.0.0.1:46342] "MULTI"
1681733993.273945 [0 127.0.0.1:46342] "INCRBY" "keyWatch" "1"
1681733993.273950 [0 127.0.0.1:46342] "EXEC"
1681733993.274279 [0 127.0.0.1:46342] "GET" "keyWatch"
```

#### Monitor info without `multi` instruction (WatchError)

For the case without `multi()` instruction I have following requests:

```
> redis-cli monitor
OK
1681737498.462228 [0 127.0.0.1:46368] "GET" "keyWatch"
1681737498.462500 [0 127.0.0.1:46368] "WATCH" "keyWatch"
1681737498.462663 [0 127.0.0.1:46368] "INCRBY" "keyWatch" "1"
1681737498.463072 [0 127.0.0.1:46368] "MULTI"
1681737498.463081 [0 127.0.0.1:46368] "EXEC"
```

Also in this second case is present the `MULTI` instruction, but between it and the `EXEC` there aren't any requests.
The `keyWatch` exception is raised by the `EXEC` instruction  in fact the MONITOR does not show the last `"GET" "keyWatch"` request (look at the first MONITOR log and you find the last `"GET" "keyWatch"` request).

> All this suggest me that the exception is caused by the execution of:
> `"INCRBY" "keyWatch" "1"` outside of the block `MULTI/EXEC`.

If someone can confirm this and explain better the behavior is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [WATCH](https://redis.io/commands/watch/), [MULTI](https://redis.io/commands/multi/), and [EXEC](https://redis.io/commands/exec/) are designed to work together. Specifically, calls to MULTI and EXEC allow the queued commands to be executed in isolation. Redis calls this a [transaction](https://redis.io/docs/manual/transactions/).

Here's how it works:

```
MULTI                          <- start queueing commands
INCR someKey                   <- queue this command
SET someOtherKey someValue     <- queue this command
UNLINK someThirdKey            <- queue this command
EXEC                           <- execute all the queued commands
```

While these commands are being queued, other commands can come in. These  other commands might change keys that are part of the transaction, which could be bad. Enter WATCH.

WATCH is used to, well, watch those keys. If they have been changed by the time EXEC is called, EXEC will return an error. You then need to run code to retry the transaction (or maybe generate an error, depending on you needs).

If they haven't been changed, then EXEC executes all the queued commands and life goes on.

It works like this:

```
WATCH someKey someOtherKey     <- watch these for changes
MULTI                          <- start queueing commands
INCR someKey                   <- queue this command
SET someOtherKey someValue     <- queue this command
UNLINK someThirdKey            <- queue this command
EXEC                           <- either error or execute queued commands
```

Note that you don't *have* to watch a key as part of a transaction, as my example above shows. In this case, I don't care if someone changes the thing I'm going to delete.

Transaction in Redis aren't what developers often think they are. If you want to get deeper in the details, there is a [guide to transactions](https://redis.io/docs/manual/transactions/) on the Redis website.

Comment: Thanks. Remains me to understand why is raised the exception in my code if I remove `multi()` instruction: in this case (with `redis-cli monitor`) I see that the instructions `MULTI/EXEC` are executed despite the `multi()` instruction is not present, and between `MULTI/EXEC` there are not executed instructions. Your answer suggests me that `EXEC` sees the modification of `keyWatch` and raise the Exception. Instead if `multi()` is present the modification of `keyWatch` occurs between `MULTI/EXEC` and this prevent from the Exception. Is it right?

Comment: My guess is the redis-py is queueing on your behalf when you call .multi() and then when you call .exec() it's sending what was queued on the *client*. If .multi() is never called, redis-py has an empty queue and so sends that.

Comment: Bottom line is that calling EXEC without a MULTI is not something that makes sense semantically. EXEC assumes that MULTI has been called. That's just how it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the pipeline's behavior changes when you call watch on it.

You're using a pipeline, which batches the commands and sends them in one go. Its `transaction` parameter is `True` by default, which means when all the commands are sent to redis, they will be wrapped with a `MULTI` and `EXEC` which makes that sequence atomic, so other commands from other clients will not be interleaved in your sequence. If you specified `transaction` as `False`, the commands will still be batched up and sent in one go, but they won't be wrapped between `MULTI` and `EXEC` when they are run on redis. This means other commands redis receives around the same time can be interleaved between your sequence of commands.

When you use a pipeline, all the commands you call on it will get sandwiched between a `MULTI` and `EXEC` for you. This is the default. So typically you never need to call multi or exec on the pipeline, because it's designed to wrap your commands for you.

The `WATCH` command only applies to transactions (which are typically made with pipelines). It basically turns it into a *conditional* transaction. It will only be performed if your watched key was **not** modified by *anyone* between the `WATCH` and `EXEC` arriving.

*It's worth noting that only the watch method on a pipeline works. The watch method on a regular `Redis` instance has no implementation; it gives a warning to use a pipeline instead (as of redis-py 5.0.1)*

However, there's a nuance when using the watch command on a pipeline, because `WATCH` is used for redis to know whether the transaction should be conditional or not, it needs to arrive before the transaction begins; it can't arrive after `MULTI`, that would be in the middle of the transaction. But the pipeline wraps everything in a transaction by default. So, the `watch` command on a pipeline ***breaks the pipeline's batching and wrapping behavior***. Now, after you call the watch method, any command you call on the pipe after that, like getting keys, setting keys, etc, they all actually get sent to redis instantly; they don't wait for you to call execute anymore. The commands are no longer batched. So when you call execute, it's basically sending an empty queue, hence the `MULTI` and `EXEC` you see with nothing in between them.

Since the pipe wraps all its commands in a `MULTI` and `EXEC` to represent a transaction, redis needs to know *before* it receives the transaction, whether it is to be a conditional transaction or not. So the watch method on pipe breaks its default behavior. So you have to explicitly call `pipe.multi()` to re-engage the batching and wrapping behavior.

Why the `WatchError` when you don't call multi after the watch? That's because, since watch breaks the batching, your watch command is sent, and then the incr command is sent, which modifies the key you were watching. Then your `MULTI` and `EXEC` arrive when you call `pipe.execute()`. Thus the key was changed between the delimiters `WATCH` and `EXEC`. So you get the `WatchError`.

The guarantee redis gives with using `WATCH` before issuing a transaction is basically this:

> *I'm gonna guarantee you, that from the moment I get your `WATCH` command, if there is **any** modification on that key between **then**, and the moment that I receive your `EXEC` command, then I'm gonna tell you with a `WatchError` and not perform the transaction*